# What crafted items have the best sustainable profit margins in Rage?

Tags: rage

I was wondering, does anyone know which recipes have the highest sustainable profit margins in *Rage*? Specifically, recipes with ingredients I can repeatedly purchase from merchants.

Comment: Sorry, this is way off topic, but: Is rage a good game or an awesome game? What would you compare it to? I'm wondering if I should get it...

Comment: Rage is like Half Life 2 meets Borderlands. The driving, aiming and weapons are all better but there's less to do and less to shoot at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing through, the best answer I can come up with is that there really isn't a recipe good for your personal economy. Instead, craft lots of wingsticks and pop rockets and go do a few rounds of Mutant Bash TV. You can average something like $600-$700 per episode.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make money I've found is once you get to Subway Town, go to Stew, the man upstairs who sells one product at a time for cheap. Most of his products will make you lose money, but if he's selling the `Viper Rockets`, simply buy all you can and then go sell them to the shop a little ways away. Do this over a bunch of times and you'll reach the $10,000 in-game limit (lame!). I used this to max out all of my ammo, shields, homing rockets, you name it and left with a full $10,000 to boot.

If he's selling something else, just go outside to the Wasteland and then come right back into Subway Town and he should be selling something else. Do this until he's selling the `Viper Rockets`.